# JPA OneToMany : List vs Set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities: `UserAccount` and `Notification`. These have a relationship as shown below.

```
 public class UserAccount {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String emailId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USERS_NOTIFICATIONS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_NAME") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NOTIFICATION_ID") })
    private List<Notification> notifications;

    //setters, getter, equals and hashcode
 }
```

Both `equals()` and `hashcode()` are overridden (generated by the IDE with business key/primary key).

Given a `UserAccount`, when I add the first `Notification`, it results in an INSERT statement. But on further addition for the same `UserAccount`, it first deletes and then inserts:

```
Hibernate: delete from USERS_NOTIFICATIONS where USER_NAME=?
Hibernate: insert into USERS_NOTIFICATIONS (USER_NAME, NOTIFICATION_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into USERS_NOTIFICATIONS (USER_NAME, NOTIFICATION_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into USERS_NOTIFICATIONS (USER_NAME, NOTIFICATION_ID) values (?, ?)
//as many inserts as the notifications the user has
```

The same happens with every `UserAccount`. If I replace the `List` with `Set`, a normal INSERT occurs. I found the reason after reading this [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-collections-mostefficientupdate) and a [blog](http://assarconsulting.blogspot.in/2009/08/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-then-re.html).

**Observations from docs**

- In a unidirectional `@OneToMany` association, `Set` is preferred.

> It should be clear that indexed `Collections` and `Sets` allow the most efficient operations in terms of adding, removing and updating elements.

- In a bidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship (`@ManyToOne` managing), `List` and `Bags` are efficient.

> `Bags` and `Lists` are the most efficient inverse `Collections`.

---

Having said that, which is more preferable:

1. A `Set` over a `List` in a unidirectional `@OneToMany` mapping?
2. Or, do I have to tweak my domain model by adding a bidirectional relationship to use a `List`, especially when there are duplicates?

Comment: One would have thought that you use a List when you want ordering, and use a Set when you don't; choose your model based on what is needed to be modelled ... irrespective of any persistence solution. Any persistence solution ought to be able to handle either

Comment: @DataNucleus: One would have thought that. One would also have thought that Hibernate would handle adding to a unidirectional map efficiently. One sometimes finds that ones thoughts were misguided!

Comment: @DataNucleas: Even i thought it was that way, but after getting the problem i mentioned above and going through the documentation i found that its something more than that.

Comment: @shazintc and Tom, I subscribe to the thought that I design my model and then apply persistence to that, and with DataNucleus JPA it will persist what I throw at it (and if it won't then I raise a bug and I fix it so that it will). Persistence should be transparent.

Comment: @VladMihalcea, what are your thoughts, please?

Comment: @ThorbenJanssen, what are your thoughts, please?

Answer (score 23):

I faced this problem not so long ago...

I found this article: Performance Antipatterns of One To Many
Association in Hibernate https://fedcsis.org/proceedings/2013/pliks/322.pdf

in short:

- Bag semantics -> `List` / `Collection` + `@OneToMany` -> One Element Added: 1 delete, N inserts , One Element Removed: 1 delete, N inserts
- List semantics -> `List` + `@OneToMany` + `@IndexColumn` / `@OrderColumn` -> One Element Added: 1 insert, M updates, One Element Removed: 1 delete, M updates
- Set semantics -> `Set` + `@OneToMany` ->  One Element Added: 1 insert , One Element Removed: 1 delete

For me: yes that mean that you have to change your `List` to `Set` for  unidirectional `@OneToMany`. So I changed my model to match with Hibernate expectations and that cause a lot of issues because the view part of the application was relying on `List` mostly...

In one hand the `Set` is a logical choice for me because there are no duplications, in the other hand `List` were easier to deal with.

So JPA/Hibernate forced me to change the model object and that was not the first time, when you are using `@EmbededId` you do something that you probably won't do in the same way without JPA/Hibernate. And when you have to be aware of `HibernateProxy` in all the application especially in equals methods ... `else if(object instanceof HibernateProxy) {` ..., you notice the JPA/Hibernate persitence layer is a little bit intrusive in others layers.

But when I use directely JDBC I also use to change the model or the buisness methods to facilitate the persistence...
Layers isolation is may be a dream or cost too much to be done at 100%?

And you can order a `Set` if they are `SortedSet` like `TreeSet` with the annotation `@OrderBy`

That bring a problem when some code rely on `List` and cannot be changed (such as JSF/PrimeFaces `<dataTable>` or `<repeat>` components)
So you have to change your `Set` into `List` and go back to `Set` but if you do `setNotifications(new HashSet<>(notificationList))` you will have extra queries because the set is a `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet` managed by Hibernate... So I used `addAll()` and `removeAll()` instead of setters:

```
protected <E> void updateCollection(@NonNull Collection<E> oldCollection, @NonNull Collection<E> newCollection) {
    Collection<E> toAdd = new ArrayList<>(newCollection) ;
    toAdd.removeAll(oldCollection) ;

    Collection<E> toRemove = new ArrayList<>(oldCollection) ;
    toRemove.removeAll(newCollection) ;

    oldCollection.removeAll(toRemove) ;
    oldCollection.addAll(toAdd) ;
}
```

Mind the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of your `@Entity`...

One other problem is that you need to Master both JPA and Hibernate if you want to use JPA with Hibernate as the implementation because the Set/List/Bag semantic is from Hibernate not from JPA (correct me if I'm wrong)

A specification is made for abstracting the implementation to not depend on one specific vendor. Although most of JavaEE specs succed, JPA failed for me and I gave up to be independent of Hibernate

Comment: Thanks for the link to Patrycja Wegrzynowicz's article, it's a good one.

Comment: Article link now appears to be broken

Answer (score 1):

List: Allows duplicate elements in it.

Set: All elements should be unique.

Now, delete may be happening because you are over-writing element in list, and so when you modify persisted entity of     UserAccount type, it is removing the entity which is in list previously.

Comment: No.. That isn't the case. Please read the documentations I have listed. It has the reason for the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Set when I do not need ordering. This enables also set-operations.
On the other hand, I use a List if ordering is required.

The semantic of the container is in my eyes the relevant aspect to decide which one to use.