# What to choose between Set and List in hibernate

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I have no any special ideas to have my collection ordered or not to allow duplicates in the collection. In my entity class what should I use ? Set or a List? Is there any consideration in performance wise ?

Lets say we want to perform CRUD operations on this entity . I don't want to have the results ordered . So what should I use ? List or Set in the Entity. What should be user in order to maximize performance

What are the valid cases of using List and Set in an entity considering performance ? Not for ordering or to restrict duplicates?

Comment: I think this one is too broad.  The answer is generally "It depends on.".  Lists and Sets have both valid use cases.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655392/which-java-type-do-you-use-for-jpa-collections-and-why and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101882/jpa-onetomany-list-vs-set

Comment: @vels4j sorry vels. The first link does not discuss the performance wise and I know that list for ordering and set for allow duplicates. Second link does not have an  answer

Comment: @ViktorSeifert yes I accept that this seems broad. But a detailed answer will be handy If someone can address wider range concerns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in another post given in the links in comment by vels4j, the following is definitely true.

> List: Allows duplicate elements in it.
>
> Set: All elements should be unique.

If you talk about performance, one point that I'm aware of is as follows:

If you take a `List` & map it to a table using Hiberante, you need to add an extra column as the index. This column will work as position/index/order of the element in the `List` because `List` is an ordered collection. See [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-indexed) for more details on index.

In case of `Set` no such column is required.

Now take an example where you need to remove an element from the `List/Set`.

In case of `List`, after removing element, you need to update all other elements of the List to update their index. This is an overhead.

While in case of `Set`, as you don't have index column, you need not to worry about other elements' index.

So my suggestion is: If you don't need your collection to be in a particular order while fetching it from the database, you should go for `Set`.

Comment: thanks Ras ,I also feel that way .Anyway I wanted to confirm it from an expert. here is my upvote for you. I'll wait more to accept an answer.

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage sure. Even I'm looking for some more useful answers. This is just one point that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Find an element by value in a `HashSet` is `O(1)`. In an `ArrayList`, it's `O(n)`. But dictionary structure `HashSet` is probably a bit slower than an `ArrayList`. And `ArrayLists` are faster at random access.