# Hibernate: Why SET is better than List for *to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections

I am learning hibernate with JPA.
With one to many relationship, I got a issue of lazy initialization. Then I changed fetch type as EAGER, it was showing "can not fetch multiple bags".

Then I changed my List into Set. I wonder its working fine.

But I want to know the reason, why set is better than list.

Kindly explain me to understand the functionality of set and List.

Comment: Can you post the piece of the code ??

Comment: I dont think its has anything to do with conversion from List to Set, both will work if configuration is fine. Moreover Set is preferred over list because Set doesn't allow duplicates objects which means you will always have unique set of elements in Set.

Comment: I use whichever suits the data my application requires. No persistence mechanism should EVER determine your choice. Do you need ordering ? use List. etc.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your comments. I created an entity which has a onetomany relation with second entity and second is having onetomany with third. I tried to access elements from third entity then i got above scenario. Here with list its giving exception while starting the server. But with set all is working fine.

Comment: so if you get some exception, then address the cause of the exception or, if it is a problem inside your persistence solution, you raise a bug on that software. There are more than one JPA implementations around (not that some companies out there would know it). Suggest you update your QUESTION with the actual problem you encounter, with details.

Comment: here it is explained very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562678/986160

Answer (score -1):

Set is a collection that cannot contain duplicate elements.

List is an ordered collection and can contain duplicate elements. You can access any element from it’s index. List is more like array with dynamic length.

Lookup from a HashSet is constant time O(1), when lookup from ArrayList will take time O(n). So HashSet performance will become more reliable than ArrayList. For more detail you can read it [here for list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) and [here for set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html).